# Apex Test for SSO with Google Accounts query - 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature'

Tags: apex

I have taken this from reddit.com/r/salesforce, as I thought this would be helpful for the audience here at SFSE.

Original link is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/4h13g7/getting_started_with_an_apex_test/).

I'm implementing SSO to allow my team to use their google accounts to login to Salesforce. Everything works like it should, but I needed to make a small change in the autocreated reg handler so that it wouldn't update the users email address. Not a big deal... until I tried to write a test to cover the 75% requirement.

After hours of googling, I can't even seem to get started. This is the class

**Class**

```
global class AutocreatedRegHandler1461772861054 implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{
global boolean canCreateUser(Auth.UserData data) {
    return false;
}

global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    if(!canCreateUser(data)) {
        return null;
    }
    User u = new User();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='Standard User'];
    u.username = data.username + '@myorg.com';
    u.email = data.email;
    u.lastName = data.lastName;
    u.firstName = data.firstName;
    String alias = data.username;
    if(alias.length() > 8) {
        alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
    }
    u.alias = alias;
    u.languagelocalekey = UserInfo.getLocale();
    u.localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
    u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.timeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
    u.profileId = p.Id;
    return u;
}

global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    User u = new User(id=userId);
    return;
}
}
```

**Test class**

```
@isTest
public class AutocreatedRegHandler1461772861054Test {
    static testMethod void updateUserTest(){
        AutocreatedRegHandler1461772861054 rh = new AutocreatedRegHandler1461772861054();
    rh.updateUser();
    }
}
```

Error that is being returned is:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature [AutocreatedRegHandler1461772861054].updateUser()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass arguments with the same signature as the original method you're testing, ie

```
rh.updateuser(userId, PortalId, Auth.userdata)
```

but before you can pass them in, you need to create them in code.

there's an example test class [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_auth_plugin.htm) you can base yours off (just below the main class)